# Finding anagaram(s) of dictionary words

Tags: java, algorithm, anagram

How can I take an input word (or sequence of letters) and output a word from a dictionary that contains exactly those letters?

Does java has an English dictionary class (list of words) that I can use, or are there open source implementations of this?

How can I optimize my code if this needs to be done repeatedly?

Comment: google for "wordlist" and you'll find plenty of lists of English words.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Convert your dictionary into an [anagram dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram_dictionary). In an anagram dictionary, the words are indexed by their letters in sorted alphabetical order. To look up anagrams for a certain word, you sort its letters and look up corresponding ones from the anagram dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

Two words are said to be anagrams if they have the ***exact same letters, exact same number*** of times.

The check for anagram is to sort the letters of both the words and check for equality:

```
sort_letters(word1) == sort_letters(word2)
```

Now to find all the anagrams of a given dictionary word say `word1`, I would find all the words in the dictionary for which the above test holds. To optimize the search we can just search for words that are of ***same length***.

If we have to do this repeatedly its better to do some ***preprocessing***. We can build something like a `HashMap` where in we would map a `string` to a set of `strings` which are anagrams. Something like:

```
Bad ==> Dab
Cat ==> Act, Tac
.....
```

Now given any word I can look into the `hashMap` to get all its anagrams.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Anagrams2 example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/algorithms/examples/Anagrams2.java)  from Sun site as a starting point

For improved performance, you can have a cache of anagrams for frequently used/recently used words.Consider using WeakHashMap for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

As [unicornaddict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628379/anagram-of-a-word/2628425#2628425) mentioned, you can fairly easily determine whether or not two words are anagrams by sorting, however this is inefficient, especially if you are doing it repeatedly.

A prepared hash-table would probably be the best solution, by loading up your dictionary into it at the beginning of the program. A fairly easy-to-write algorithm for hashing/comparing would be

```
uint HashSomeWord(string someWord)
{
   uint hashVal = 0;
   //foreach letter in someword
   {
      //hashVal += letter.ValueAsInteger
   }
   return hashVal;
}
```

then

```
bool IsAnagram(string inputWord, string compareTo)
{
    if(inputWord == null
       || compareTo == null
       || inputWord.Length != compareTo.Length
       || HashSomeWord(inputWord) != HashSomeSome(compareTo))
    {
       return false;
    }
    if(sort_letters(inputWord) == sort_letters(compareTo))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Java is pretty rusty, but I think that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

From my POV, the key to this assignment is to find a function (`hashFunc`) that maps strings to numbers so that 1) two anagrams are mapped to the same number, 2) two non-anagrams are mapped to different numbers. Once the function is found, it can be simply applied to inputs thus avoiding tedious string comparisons:

```
   if(hashFunc(word1) == hashFunc(word2)) -> word2 is anagram of word1
```

> Does java has an English dictionary class (list of words) that I can use, or are there open source implementations of this?

On unix systems, you can start with the [words file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_%28Unix%29)

> How can I optimize my code if this needs to be done repeatedly?

Turn the dictionary into a hash table using precalculated `hashFunc`.